# Is there a way to use the rolling function to compute statistics on multiple columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I am working on a large dataset in which I am computing a rolling window calculation based on time. I need to find the slope, y-intercept and r2 between two columns (co2d and co).

Based on this code:

```
df.rolling('20s', min_periods=2).insert_function_here()
```

I am looking for a way to output the statistics between those two columns. I have a way of running the code currently, but it is lengthy and not very pythonic, so I was curious if there was a built in way to do so!

Here is a sample of my dataset :

```
{'co': {0: 425.07144266999995, 1: 425.06915346999995, 2: 425.06915346999995, 3: 433.21636567, 4: 433.21636567, 
        5: 433.21803501999995, 6: 433.21803501999995, 7: 411.10666247, 8: 411.10666247, 9: 411.38779539999996, 
        10: 411.38779539999996, 11: 420.62025938000005, 12: 420.62025938000005, 13: 421.1036325, 14: 421.1036325, 
        15: 413.96486982000005, 16: 413.96486982000005, 17: 413.44999135, 18: 413.44999135, 19: 408.73726959}, 
 'gps_time': {0: '2019-11-18 14:37:51.000000', 1: '2019-11-18 14:37:51.000000', 2: '2019-11-18 14:37:52.000000', 
              3: '2019-11-18 14:37:53.000000', 4: '2019-11-18 14:37:54.000000', 5: '2019-11-18 14:37:54.000000', 
              6: '2019-11-18 14:37:55.000000', 7: '2019-11-18 14:37:56.000000', 8: '2019-11-18 14:37:56.000000', 
              9: '2019-11-18 14:37:57.000000', 10: '2019-11-18 14:37:57.000000', 11: '2019-11-18 14:37:58.000000', 
              12: '2019-11-18 14:37:59.000000', 13: '2019-11-18 14:38:00.000000', 14: '2019-11-18 14:38:00.000000', 
              15: '2019-11-18 14:38:01.000000', 16: '2019-11-18 14:38:02.000000', 17: '2019-11-18 14:38:02.000000', 
              18: '2019-11-18 14:38:03.000000', 19: '2019-11-18 14:38:04.000000'}, 
 'co2d': {0: 380.58647938, 1: 381.44674445, 2: 451.67041972, 3: 451.67041972, 4: 451.66555392, 5: 451.66555392, 
          6: 456.29788806, 7: 456.29788806, 8: 456.29412627, 9: 456.29412627, 10: 520.61774288, 11: 520.61774288, 
          12: 520.62904898, 13: 520.62904898, 14: 630.97037738, 15: 630.97037738, 16: 630.9919346, 17: 630.9919346, 
          18: 512.76133406, 19: 512.76133406}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `.apply` to apply `.rolling` and use `.agg` for some custom function.
- This can be used to make a column-wise calculation with `axis=1`, or row-wise with `axis=0`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# given your dataset as data

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert gps_time to datetime format
df.gps_time = pd.to_datetime(df.gps_time)

# set index
df.set_index('gps_time', inplace=True)

# some function to aggregate
def my_mean(x: pd.Series):
    return np.mean(x)


# some function to create new dataframe columns
# this will add new columns to the dataframe inplace
def test(x: pd.Series, df: pd.DataFrame):
    df[f'{x.name}_rolling_mean'] = x.rolling('20s', min_periods=2).agg(my_mean)


# apply test
df.apply(lambda x: test(x, df))

# disply(df.head(6))
                             co        co2d  co_rolling_mean  co2d_rolling_mean
gps_time                                                                       
2019-11-18 14:37:51  425.071443  380.586479              NaN                NaN
2019-11-18 14:37:51  425.069153  381.446744       425.070298         381.016612
2019-11-18 14:37:52  425.069153  451.670420       425.069917         404.567881
2019-11-18 14:37:53  433.216366  451.670420       427.106529         416.343516
2019-11-18 14:37:54  433.216366  451.665554       428.328496         423.407923
2019-11-18 14:37:54  433.218035  451.665554       429.143419         428.117529
```

### multiple calculations w/ different columns

- In this case pass the entire dataframe to a function

```py
# function
def calculations(v: pd.DataFrame):
    rolling_co = v.co.rolling('20s', min_periods=2).mean()
    rolling_co2 = v.co2d.rolling('20s', min_periods=2).mean()
    calc_div = rolling_co2 / rolling_co
    v['rolling_dif'] = calc_div  # adds an inplace update to df


# call function
calculations(df)

# display(df.head(5))
                             co        co2d  rolling_dif
gps_time                                                
2019-11-18 14:37:51  425.071443  380.586479          NaN
2019-11-18 14:37:51  425.069153  381.446744     0.896361
2019-11-18 14:37:52  425.069153  451.670420     0.951768
2019-11-18 14:37:53  433.216366  451.670420     0.974800
2019-11-18 14:37:54  433.216366  451.665554     0.988512
2019-11-18 14:37:54  433.218035  451.665554     0.997609
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful for the separated calculations! Is there a way to do the same calculation on both columns concurrently (ie co2d/co to get the slope, r2, y int of the correlation between those 2 columns)?